# how to use encrypted neo4j connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Neo4J cluster in GCP environment.
I'm trying to create a secure connection to it from AWS elastic beanstalk, but I'm getting the following error:

```
  File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 36, in _create_session
    session = self._driver.session()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neo4j/v1/session.py", line 148, in session
    session = Session(self)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neo4j/v1/session.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.connection = connect(driver.host, driver.port, driver.ssl_context, **driver.config)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neo4j/v1/connection.py", line 427, in connect
    if not store.match_or_trust(host, der_encoded_server_certificate):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/neo4j/v1/connection.py", line 380, in match_or_trust
    f_out = os_open(self.path, O_CREAT | O_APPEND | O_WRONLY, 0o600)  # TODO: Windows
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/wsgi/.neo4j/known_hosts'
```

My code looks like this:

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(url=host,
                              auth=basic_auth(username,password),
                              encrypted=True)
session = driver.session()
```

If I use `encrypted=False` the session is created successfully.

How can I solve this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python driver stores the certificate after first usage in `$HOME/.neo4j/known_hosts`. It looks like the `wsgi` user cannot create that directory due to missing permissions. To solve it try this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /home/wsgi/.neo4j; sudo chown wsgi /home/wsgi/.neo4j
```